# jquery "show" effect shows wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, mouseenter

I'm trying to get two icons, "Up" and "Down", to turn a darker color when I hover over them. So I made two more icons, "UpHover" and "DownHover", which start out hidden, and are respectively shown when I mouseenter Up or Down, and hidden again when I mouseleave them. Down works normally, but for some reason, when I mouseenter Up, both Up and Down are hidden, and both UpHover and DownHover are shown.

When I erase the line `$(".UpHover").show();` (I put asterisks around it below) the effect stops, so the error must be in that line. But I can't for the life of me figure out why that line would have anything to do with Down or DownHover. What am I missing?

```
<%= link_to image_tag("Up.png", class: "Up"), '#' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("Down.png", class: "Down"), '#' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("UpHover.png", class: "UpHover"), '#' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("DownHover.png", class: "DownHover"), '#' %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".UpHover").hide();
  $(".DownHover").hide();
  $(".Up").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".Up").hide();
    ***$(".UpHover").show();***
  });
  $(".UpHover").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".Up").show();
    $(".UpHover").hide();
  });
  $(".Down").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".Down").hide();
    $(".DownHover").show();
  });
  $(".DownHover").mouseleave(function () {
    $(".Down").show();
    $(".DownHover").hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be done more easily with CSS?

Comment: You could probably solve this much easier using the CSS pseudo class :hover  Try this link for a quick intro : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: When you hide `Up`, `Down` moves into its place. So the mouse enters `Down`, and it gets hidden.

Comment: misspelled `text/javascipt`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the images so that the replacement is next to the image it replaces.

```
<%= link_to image_tag("Up.png", class: "Up"), '#' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("UpHover.png", class: "UpHover"), '#' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("Down.png", class: "Down"), '#' %>
<%= link_to image_tag("DownHover.png", class: "DownHover"), '#' %>
```

What's happening is that when you hide `Up`, the `Down` image move up to fill in that space. Since that's where the mouse is, the `$(".Down").mouseenter` event fires, and it gets hidden as well.

When you reorder it, `UpHover` fills in the `Up` place.

Comment: Wow, never would have thought that. Thank you, I'll accept your answer as soon as I can!

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, just use CSS, and you won't need any JavaScript for this:

```
<%= link_to "#", class: "Up" %>
<%= link_to "#", class: "Down" %>

.Up, .Down
{
    display: inline-block;
    height: /* height of image */;
    width: /* width of image */;
}

.Up
{
    background-image: url(Up.png);
}

.Down
{
    background-image: url(Down.png);
}

.Up:hover
{
    background-image: url(UpHover.png);
}

.Down:hover
{
    background-image: url(DownHover.png);
}
```

Comment: Are there any benefits to using CSS?

Comment: @user3739453 Certainly. Keeping styling in your CSS and out of your JavaScript is one of the hallmarks of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). So the more you can do that, the better.

Comment: But does it increase speed or prevent bugs or something?

Comment: It does not prevent bugs directly, but it generally improves readability, reusability and reduces code complexity.

Comment: @user3739453 To the extent that it reduces the amount of code you need, it can be helpful in reducing the likelihood of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSS pseudo class :hover to do this, not javascript.

You can define a special set of styles for when the element has a mousover. Specify the alternate image for this style.

Comment: Are there any benefits to using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Better to change the background-position or change the class on hovering like,

```
$('.Up').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('active');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```